# C# Why should i limit myself to List or Stack ? ( instead of having both)

Tags: java, c#, collections, list, stack

`List` is implemented in C# exactly as `Stack`, see:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.push?view=netframework-4.8#remarks
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Given that:

Why should developers choose, List ***or*** Stack,  while in fact they can have **"2 in 1"**.
(Implementing `Pop` for `List`,  would make it 2-in-1! ).

Coming from more flexible languages, I don't want to commit to a limiting-collection-type. Starting with Stack, maybe later as problem changes, I'll need to access an `[index]`, alternatively  w/Lists, maybe later need `Pop` or  `List1.Add (List2.Pop())` often.

1. Why doesn't `RemoveAt()` return a value? What damage would happen if it returned a value (as actually done in Java `ArrayList`)?
2. Why no `Pop()`?

Looking at Python, Perl, Ruby and 'e', one does wonder how come a C# `List` doesn't have `Pop()`. I want the "Swiss army knife" of arrays. i.e. `List`! It's convenient to use just one language construct, and avoid conversions, etc. As `List` is implemented using array and supports `Add` in O(1) (`Add` is just a different name for `Push`), why wasn't `Pop` added as well?

3. Why do we need a C# `Stack` when `List` could easily do all `Stack` does, and more?

   Easy way to `pop` 'd make me **always** use List, hence saving the need of conversions/casting between `List` and `Stack`.

Am i the only C# dude, that wants a (slightly) more powerful List ? ( instead of having 2 weaker concepts and having to convert between them ).
( other than that c# is really good).

Update :  Wow !!  Thanks to this thread Microsoft had decided to add Pop to C# list  !!  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31828.
many thanks to the community, especially to user @Theraot.

Comment: There is no `Pop()` because it is not a queue.  There is a `Queue` implementation or a `Stack`.  Thing is, collection those types of collections have specific purposes and the implementations are optimized for that purpose.  Just because `List` can do it all, doesn't mean it does it all efficiently.

Comment: Pop is for **stack** ( not a queue) , List is implemented in C# exactly as Stack. ( both use array ),  and Stack Push is exactly List Add (same thing O(1) ).    Queue is indeed another thing, and dequeue would not easily be O(1) , Hence i only ask about Stack, and **not** Queue.

Comment: List doesn't have stack operations because list is not a stack. If you want stack operations, you should the [Stack class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netframework-4.8). The fact that they may or may not share some implementation details does not mean they are equivalent.

Comment: @rankeren: *“List is implemented in C# exactly as Stack”*: you may want to add this statement to your question, and explain why is that the case (with relevant links to the source code of .NET Framework). Reading your question, my first reaction was that list should be stored in a different way than a stack, and therefore the question makes little sense and should be downvoted. If this is not the case, it changes everything.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko -    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.push?view=netframework-4.8#remarks                https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: Your question contains several fallacies. The overall tone is more of a series of statements and opinions. When using 'Most folks want' or 'python folks know' this is called an 'appeal to the people'. This fallacy occurs when one attempts to establish the truth of a conclusion by appealing to the fact that the conclusion is widely believed to be true
Thus I have some doubt you are genuinely interested in receiving answers to your question.

Comment: @MartinK  i seriously want to know what is the reason  `RemoveAt()` does not resurn a value, as in Java ?   why i need to limit myself in C# , while it is so easy to give me 2 in price of 1 ?   want msft dude to explain their design decisions.  ( and hopefully to change them, for benefit of all)

Comment: Please learn something from the edits: ditch the txt spk, don't refer to (ephemeral!) comments, pay attention to the formatting.

Comment: If you want to influence Microsoft, this is not an effective venue. Microsoft has their own feedback channels.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the edits, you really made the post so much better.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the point of objects is to limit the things you can do with them as well as enable you to do things.

If I could add items randomly into a stack then it wouldnt be a stack.

If I pop from a list should it return the first or last item added?

Limiting behaviour and having specialised objects is a good thing because it allows you to have sensible expectations about what the object will do without knowing the detail of the implementation.

Comment: Your comment on stack, makes   sense.Thanks. However regarding **List**,  there is already RemoveAt, that lets you remove from **anywhere**, but unlike jave, it does not return the removed.

Comment: Well Python (and others) , has pop and pop0,   for list. Systemverilog has pop_front and pop_back for their 'list'.

Comment: Regarding 'Pop location is unclear', well you could say that for 'Add' too!     ( add is super helpful)

Comment: @rankeren I think you are missing the point. Add, Pop and RemoveAt don't have universal meaning. They are given meaning by the class they are in. If you add everything to all classes you just en up with a mess

Comment: **`Pop`** and **`Add`**  **do** have a  universal meaning!   Show me one language where **`Pop`**    deletes  items **_not_** from the end  (by default)?   show me one language  that **`Add`**   adds items **_not_** in the  end   (by default)?    Of  course you can invent a language where  `if (false)`  `d behave as `if(true)` does, at any other language, yet, that `d be a bad design.

Comment: SugarSnap.Pop()

Comment: int.Add(), javascript where var true is undefined

Comment: SugarSnap.Pop()  - is there a typo here ?  link ?  my google seem not to be familiar with it.    'd appriciate a link to  "int.Add(), javascript where var true is undefined"  as well.

Comment: you know you can make your own classes right?

Comment: One can invent any language , including where `a` gets the value `false`  here: `bool  a= (1==1)` .  Yet it **doesn't** mean there is no defacto standard.   Same for `pop`.  You can write your own language where `pop` does whatever, yet that doesn't mean there is no de-facto standard.  **Pop deletes from the end** ( in list)

Comment: no. pop deletes from the top of a stack.

Comment: Check python,  perl, ruby, e, and others !    **`Pop` deletes from the end** of the **_list_**. ( Why deny  something so easy to google ?  )       .Hence, **list is** (also) **used as stack** .  Where the end of the list **_is_** the top of the stack.   That's, of course, **_not_** contradictory (i.e. your usage of the world 'no' is wrong ) .    I can show you in skype, how stack is naturally modeled using list in those languages. And you'd realize that  the top of the stack could not only very well be,the end of the list.  But rather it's even the  common way, across many popular languages.

Comment: because the answer is not language dependent. stack, queue, list etc are different concepts which languages implement. sure if you are lazy you can mash em all together, but it is bad to do so. those languages are wrong

Comment: your valuable input was considered by Microsoft team.   They decided to add  Pop to List<T> .  see  :   https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31828

Answer (score 3):

> instead of having 2 weaker concepts and having to convert between them

Well, that is actually not how I see it. Since a `List` allows one effectively to execute all stack-like operations, if one really needs "both concepts in one", using a `List` allows this, so this is IMHO not a "weaker" concept.

Of course, the equivalent of a `Pop()` operation on a List requires a little bit more code, but if that really bothers you, because in your specific context you need that operation frequently, you can write an extension method for it, like this:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T Pop<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        int lastIdx = list.Count - 1;
        T lastItem = list[lastIdx];
        list.RemoveAt(lastIdx);
        return lastItem;
    }
}
```

(Similarly, you could implement something like a `PopAt` operation, which means a `RemoveAt` with returning the removed value.)

I understand your question in this sense: why did the .Net framework designers  not provide such a method directly as part of the `List<T>` class? For getting a binding answer, you need to ask those library designers. But I can imagine the follwing potential reasons:

- Mixing up two concepts in one class does not make the class more readable and understandable. Historically, arrays, lists and stacks are usually taught as different concepts in most CS courses, and the terminology which includes Push, Peek, and Pop is exclusively used the context of stacks. So having one class for each of these concepts fits better to this than mixing up two of those concepts in one class, even it would technically be possible
- Any additional feature in a class requires additional effort to specify it, implement it, test it, review it, document it, release it and maintain it. So the designers are usually very reluctant to add features which can be easily added by the users of the classes by themselves.
- The number of cases where one really needs a Pop operation on a random access list is probably small enough for justifying to let the users implement their own function in case they really require it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!    Note that all other languages I know, do have pop in there 'list'. (Python, perl, ruby, e, systemverilog, and I bet many more). Except java and c#.  C# wouldn't even return value for RemoveAt.  Go figure.

Comment: 'Add' is super common,  'Pop' is sort of undo for it,  and I find it very helpful.  ( so do so many modern languages)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a "slightly more powerful list", then implement it. Make use of extension methods to add what you want to that class. For example, the following code will give you a list that returns the value when removing an element and provides `Push` and `Pop`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class ListExtensions 
{
    public static T FetchAndRemoveAt<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        if (index >= list.Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

        var value = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);

        return value;
    }

    public static void Push<T>(this List<T> list, T value) => list.Add(value);

    public static T Pop<T>(this List<T> list) => list.FetchAndRemoveAt(list.Count-1);
}
```

It's a naïve implementation that's certainly not thread-safe, but it may meet your needs. If not, write it the way you need it to be. If you think others would find it useful, publish it as a nuget package. So rather than worrying why the designers didn't implement things the way you want, you can implement them that way very easily.

Comment: Guess, I got it wrong, the real question is why Java made its  removeAt return a value, while they could allow users to sweat on that detail.   We should also ask Python to remove pop from their list, as that is also something users need to sweat on.  I tend to believe those langs spoil their users way too much.

Comment: "*the real question is why Java made its removeAt return a value*". Indeed, that is a good question to ask. In over 15 years of using C#, you are literally the first person I've encountered that wants `RemoveAt` to return the value. I suspect that almost no Java developer has ever used that return value therefore. And Python is a dynamic language. The "Swiss Army Knife" approach of overloading a small number of types with multiple purposes makes sense for dynamic languages.

Comment: RemoveAt (0) is just pop0(aka dequeue). List as a fifo model,  is very common in some areas, ( despite O(n)) .  RemoveAt (count-1),  is pop,   very common, and also the 'undo'  of Add.   I hardly see what dynsmic typing has to do here.  Systemverilog and e are strong typed, but Support pop.   Would adding pop 'd make c# dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

> Why should developers choose, List or Stack, while in fact they can have "2 in 1". (Implementing Pop for List, would make it 2-in-1! ).

This could mean bad encapsulation. You pass your Listack to third party code, and it uses in ways that you do not expect, resulting in an invalid state for your code. There is value in limiting what objects can do. It is good for defensive programming. See also [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

---

> Coming from more flexible languages, I don't want to commit to a limiting-collection-type. Starting with Stack, maybe later as problem changes, I'll need to access an [index], alternatively w/Lists, maybe later need Pop or List1.Add (List2.Pop()) often.

Right. You may decide in the future that the type or interface you are using is not adequate and want to change it. And of course we do not want this change to propagate.

Well, if your methods receive objects by an interface, you can change the type without changing where you use it. Then, when you need to change to a type that has the same capabilities (and thus the same interfaces) plus some new ones... well, all methods that used the object before should still work, given that they use an interface that you are not removing... you are adding. So the change does not propagate out of control. See also [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

---

> Why doesn't RemoveAt() return a value?

As Raymond Chen would put it:

> features start out nonexistent and somebody has to make them happen.

-- [source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080317-00/?p=23103)

There is value in asking why the other languages do it, and whatever or not those reasoning apply to .NET. *Oh, yes, we are talking about the standard library, not the language C#.* If that reasoning applies… well...

---

> What damage would happen if it returned a value (as actually done in Java ArrayList)?

At source level, there should be no problem. Nobody is using the return value of `RemoveAt`, given that it hasn’t one, and thus, no source code would be broken.

However, IL is a stack language. And the return value would be placed in the stack, and had to be discarded with a [`pop`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.pop?view=netframework-4.8). Thus, this change would break assemblies. *We are talking of recompiling them. Existing assemblies could continue to work in an old runtime.*

That of course, does not explain why they didn't do it in the first place.

With that said, a new method could be added to `List<T>` that does what you want...

---

> Why no Pop()?

Right. Like adding a `List<T>.Pop` method. Adding that should be possible.

You could try posting an issue to [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime), maybe a merge request.

*If they don't want to do it, they will tell you why.*

And perhaps in the next release…

Why wait? You could implement `Pop` for `List<T>` as an extension method. *I like [David Arno's solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/403406/45814).*

---

> Why do we need a C# Stack when `List` could easily do all `Stack` does, and more?

You don't. And you do not need `List` either, you can work with arrays. `Stack` exists for convenience of its use cases, and so does `List`. I can only guess that the uses cases you have in mind where not considered for `List`.

However, we may want the distinction. The more limited is an object, the more certain we are about how it will be used. And thus, we may want a limited object to ensure it is not misused/abused.

---

> Easy way to pop 'd make me always use List, hence saving the need of conversions/casting between List and Stack

I would consider making an adapter for `List` that wraps it and works like a `Stack`. You may even provide [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=netcore-3.1).

---

> Am i the only C# dude, that wants a (slightly) more powerful List ?

No. Some people want, and have created other kinds of collections. There are Nugets out there… Although you are the first I have seen to want this particular change.

*I don't think "List with Pop" are good search terms, I didn’t find a library for .NET that have that.*

Perhaps what you want already exists. Perhaps you can create it and publish it for every body to use. Remember that `features start out nonexistent and somebody has to make them happen`.

Comment: Fantastic answer!    yet ..   "This could mean bad _encapsulation_...The more _limited_ is an object, the more certain we are about" .  **Correct !  but not relevant for list**  ...  If there was _no_ `removeAt`  that 'd apply to **list**.     Given `RemoveAt` , `Pop` doen't makes **list**  less _encapsulated_, nor less _limited_ .   ( `Pop` is merely a **convenient** `removeAt`+_index access_, at a common scenario).   Adding Pop to list would not make it less encapsulated not less limited .

Comment: @rankeren no, but giving `Insert`, `RemoveAt`, etc... to a `Stack` does. So, should the method use the object as a stack?

Comment: Well, you can keep stack, i care only about list.  ( BTW,  by doing many pops to a a side  stack changing an item and pushing to main stack, you can have access by index to stack as well .)

Comment: @rankeren and solution has been proposed for your list: you can wrap it, you can add an extension method, you write your own, you can propose it to the dotnet team.

Comment: on that you are absolutely right.

Comment: (Not that i care about stack, yet).  **Is** it  safe to assume that `Stack` is _limited/encapsulated_  ?      One may `Insert` at **any** location, using a trick.   ( a method that allocates _other_  stack, pops items from original to _other_, inserts the item to original , and spills _other_ on original ).

Comment: @rankeren True. Stack is well encapsulated, the code that uses it and passes it around might not. We have alternatives if we want better guarantees. Such as `ImmutableStack<T>` or `ConcurrentStack<T>`. Or perhaps we could pass a `Func<T>` for code that should only pop... even `IEnumerable<T>`. By the way, that reminds me, I do not think defensive programming is the right approach for every domain. In particular, if I'm writing both sides, it is not concurrent code, and it is not a public API, I'd be ok with relaxed guarantees. `Stack` still has on its favor showing intent and *deters* bad use.

Comment: Theraot !  Man see yourself as partly responsible .   Microsoff  decided on adding Pop  to C# List<T>.    https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31828
( wait to24 Jun).   Guess that would not have happened without  your pointer !!

Comment: @rankeren I think you misread that. It was tagged to the Future milestone on Jun 24 of this year. You can check [.NET 5.0 api for List<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) it does not contain Pop. This will probably be added for the next version afterwards. Looking at the [roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md)... Wait until .NET 6.0 on November 2021, which is a LTS (and that is good). A long wait for a small feature in my opinion. I'd still suggest the extension method in the meantime.

Comment: 'm not a C#/msft dude, but 'd like to improve humanity.   Thanks to your feedback,  C#   'd be a better place !    Soon even juniors at 8th garde,  'd  be able to  pop  from a C# List !      ( even those that haven't heard of great @David Arno, or even StackExchange)